# Dynamically change link destinations using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

On my website, I have a series of tiles that the user must be able to edit/delete etc... Normally, the tiles (Which are links to other websites like Facebook) would just link straight to their labelled destination but I want the user to be able to enable a 'delete mode' that would allow them to delete the tile by clicking on it.

These tiles are unique to each user and are called in from a database via PHP. I have added a script to the code of the tile that should allow the link to be changed depending on a JavaScript variable, however I feel there is an issue with the PHP not allowing the link to change once it has been initially loaded in.

Heres my code:

```
<script>
    var mode = 1;

    function setMode(a) {
        mode = a;
    }
</script>

<?php
    $uid = $_COOKIE["UID"];
    include '../config.php';
    if (empty($uid)) {header('Location: /error?error=7');};
    $tile_counter = 0;
    error_reporting(0);
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

    // check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die("Connect failed: ".$mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tiles where uid='$uid'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        if ($tile_trans == 1) {
            $tileColour = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
        }else{
            $tileColour = $row[colour];
        }
    //echo '<div class="tile" style="background-color:'.$tileColour.';width:'.$row[width].'px;"><img class="tileimg" src="http://'.$row[img_url].'"></div>';
    echo '
    <a id="'.$row[id].'" href="">
        <div class="tile hvr-reveal" id="tile" style="background-color:'.$tileColour.';width:'.$row[width].'px;">
            <img class="tileimg" src="http://'.$row[img_url].'">
        </div>
    </a>
    <script>
        if (mode == 1){document.getElementById("'.$row[id].'").setAttribute("href", "http://'.$row[link_url].'")}
        else if (mode == 2){document.getElementById("'.$row[id].'").setAttribute("href", "/php/tile/delete.php?id='.$row[id].'")}
    </script>';
    }
    ?>
```

There are several buttons that the user has access to that change the 'mode' variable shown above, they look like this:

```
<button onclick="setMode(2);">Delete</button></a>
```

If I set the 'mode' variable to 2 initially, the links changes correctly but I cant get the links to change when the function is called after everything is loaded up.

Comment: add some debugging in the setMode function and also inside the script tag inside the php script . maybe a console.log(mode); will solve your problem . I guess it is a problem with the scope of "mode"

Comment: Have you though of making some kind of verification with AJAX? Also, I would suggest that you create a separate js file for your script. Something like`<button id="mybutton">Delete</button></a>`

`$("#mybutton").on("click", function(){
setMode(2);
})`.

Comment: @SourabReddy This is a screenshot of the Console. The 2 appears after I have clicked the Delete mode button. http://i.imgur.com/mOtMSOg.png

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
if (mode == 1){document.getElementById("'.$row[id].'").setAttribute("href", "http://'.$row[link_url].'")}
    else if (mode == 2){document.getElementById("'.$row[id].'").setAttribute("href", "/php/tile/delete.php?id='.$row[id].'")}
```

will only run one time when the page is loaded. You should wrap it in a function that can be called when the `setMode` function is triggered by the user.

```
function updateLinks()
  {
    if (mode == 1){document.getElementById("'.$row[id].'").setAttribute("href", "http://'.$row[link_url].'")}
    else if (mode == 2){document.getElementById("'.$row[id].'").setAttribute("href", "/php/tile/delete.php?id='.$row[id].'")}
  }
```

then

```
function() setMode(mode) {
  ... whatever is already happening
  updateLinks()
}
```

The problem you will have is that you can't define that function multiple times within the PHP `while`. You need to move it outside the `while` and find a different way to reference the correct link.

Comment: I wrapped the script in the function and this works but only for the last tile that was loaded. This is a screenshot of the console now: http://i.imgur.com/DGF6Fnw.png The number at the beginning of each line is the id of each tile.

Comment: @Splycd that is because only the last definition of the function will apply and they are specific to each tile. Do you want the button click to set the mode for all tiles at the same time?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to happen.